# Execute job on distributed cassandra DSE spark cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have three node Cassandra DSE cluster and db schema with RF=3. Now I'm creating a scala application to be executed on DSE spark. Scala code is as follow :-

```
package com.spark

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object sample {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local")
  .setAppName("testing")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.40")
  .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "1g")
  .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "500M")
  .set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "30s")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val lRDD = sc.cassandraTable("dbname", "tablename")
lRDD.collect.foreach(println)
}}
```

I'm running script using

```
dse> bin/dse spark-submit --class com.spark.sample --total-executor-cores 4 /home/db-svr/sample.jar
```

So, now I want to execute my spark application from 1 node but system should do processing on 3 nodes internally and I want to monitor the same so that I can utilize RAM and processor collectively of 3 nodes. How can I do that ?

Also, this current script is taking lot of time to bring result (table size 1 million rows with 128 byte each). Is there any performance tuning parameters that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

There a few things you probably want to change. The main thing stopping you from running on multiple machines is

`.setMaster("local")`

Which instructs the application that it shouldn't use a distributed Resource Manager and instead should run everything locally in the application process. With DSE you should follow the [relevant documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/startingSpark.html#startingSpark__specifying-spark-urls) or start with the [Spark Build Examples](https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples).

In addition you most likely never want to set

`.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")`

having multiple Spark Contexts in one JVM is frought with problems and usually means things are not set up correctly.

Comment: Hi Russ, 

So now its distributing on all nodes but my concern is that it is taking lot of memory like i executed the program on 1 million result set which is nothing but around 148 MB data but task manager shows RAM is occupied more then 2 GB showing worker/executor task on Monitor.

Also, it keeps on holding the memory after the completion of task. How can I free my memory after task execution ?

Comment: Spark resources are held until an application is shut down and uses memory as set by you the user. The heaps themselves will fluctuate in size but the resource manager will consider the full heap in use for the purposes of job scheduling.

Comment: As you can see I have created a simple code to display set of records on console after which ideally it should stop. So , Is there anything that I may need to write in application code or while invoking spark-submit so that memory will get released after printing data on screen ?